# Como passar uma função como argumento em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tentei de várias formas, usando variáveis locais e atribuindo a elas os dois métodos mas não funcionou, alguém sabe onde eu errei?

```py
def game(init, loop, frame_rate=60):
    from time import sleep

    stop = False
    time_per_frame = 1 / frame_rate
    frame = 1

    init()

    while True:
        if stop == True:
            break

        sleep(time_per_frame)
        frame += 1

        if frame == frame_rate:
            frame = 1

        loop()

def method1():
    print('Testando', end='')

def method2():
    print('.', end='')

game(method1(), method2())
```

ERRO:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\Downloads\teste.py", line 28, in <module>
    game(method1(), method2())
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\Downloads\teste.py", line 8, in game
    init()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu rodei o teu código e eu vou te dizer o que esta acontecendo com ele. 
Primeiro vamos a mensagem de erro

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\Downloads\teste.py", line 28, in <module>
    game(method1(), method2())
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\Downloads\teste.py", line 8, in game
    init()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

A mensagem esta dizendo que você esta tentando chamar um valor `None` como se fosse um método, ou seja, o valor que game esta recebendo no parâmetro `init` é um valor `None` e não a função `method1`. 
Este erro ocorre porque quando você executa a instrução `game(method1(), method2())`você **não está passando as funções** `method1` e `method2` como argumento para a função game mas sim as chamando-as e **passando o retorno** delas para a função game que no caso seria o valor `None`, e quando chega na instrução `init()` dentro da função game o erro ocorre, porque naquele momento o valor é nulo.

Para passar a função como argumento você se referencia apenas ao nome dela e não usa parenteses

```
game(method1, method2)
```